# Changing dynamically page Title by div in viewport

Tags: html, dynamic, viewport

I recently used the Viewport plugin and I'm trying to change page title on website when people will scroll down and up. I'm getting Original title + undefined. Thank you!

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {   
var inview = $('div:in-viewport:first').attr('id');     


if (inview == 'about') 
{

var newtitle = 'About'

} else if (inview == 'Offers') 
{

var newtitle = 'Offer'

}  

else if (inview == 'contact') 
{

var newtitle = 'Contact'

}  



document.title = 'Orginal Site Title |' + newtitle;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a case of jQuery and or the plugin not working as expected when creating a CSS style selector. Can you try using a chained method instead?

`$('div:in-viewport').first().attr('id')`

Comment: Thank you for reply. Tried but not functional.

Comment: Ahh, just checked your live site. The problem is you're not being specific enough with your selector so it's grabbing the first div on the page which doesn't have an ID. This is what's throwing the `undefined` in the title.

If you add a class selector to your jQuery selector it will work: 

`$('div.container:in-viewport:first').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `newtitle` variable outside of the `if/else if` statements and reassign it.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var inview = $('div:in-viewport:first').attr('id');
    var newtitle;

    if (inview == 'about') {

        newtitle = 'About'

    } else if (inview == 'Offers') {

        newtitle = 'Offer'

    } else if (inview == 'contact') {

        newtitle = 'Contact'

    }

    document.title = 'Orginal Site Title |' + newtitle;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried that, but still getting undefined.

Comment: Do you have a link to the live page? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Here is the live page. It is in Czech language so I hope it's not a problem. Thank you [link](http://18339.w39.wedos.ws/domains/radegast/)